# Force over Area diagram

Tags: thermodynamics

In this question a have to draw a F/A diagram in function of p-V (pressure-volume) diagram below. [image]

I think in a intuitive way that this graphic of F/A it´s going to be the same graphic because Pressure it´s equal to Force and Volume it´s proportional to Area.

Comment: Here, from a) volume seems proportional to length and Area seems to be independent

Comment: Force is not equal to Pressure. It is proportional to Pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think in a intuitive way that this graphic of F/A it´s going to be the same graphic because Pressure it´s equal to Force and Volume it´s proportional to Area.

The pressure $p$ left of the piston exerts a force $F$ on the piston with cross-section $A$:

$$F=pA$$

So:

$$p=\frac FA$$

A graph for (a) of $\frac FA$ v. volume $V$ will indeed be similarly shaped as for (b), assuming (b) is indeed a $p,V$ diagram.